# How to create custom Freedesktop menu categories?

Tags: freedesktop

I can't seem to create "Security" as a custom top-level Freedesktop category. (I have Sparky Linux with Openbox.)

I did research and everyone agrees you can do it in three easy steps:

1. Create a security.menu file at /etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/
2. Create a security.directory file at /usr/share/desktop-directories/
3. Create a appName.desktop file at ~/.local/share/applications/

After creating the three files, the `appName.desktop` entry does indeed appear in my jgmenu, but under an **Other** category and not the **Security** category I created. For whatever reason, the menu doesn't recognize my new category and just sticks my app in the Other category because it doesn't know what to do. I've double-checked the `.menu` and `.directory` files multiple times, and I'm formatting them as I should. (contents of both appear below)

Is there anything else I should be doing?

**security.menu**

```
> <!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
> "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd"> 
> <Menu> 
>   <Name>Applications</Name>
>   <Menu>
>     <Name>Security</Name>
>     <Directory>security.directory</Directory>
>     <Include>
>       <And>
>       <Category>Security</Category>
>       </And>
>     </Include>
>   </Menu>
> </Menu>
```

**security.directory**

```
> [Desktop Entry] 
> Type=Directory 
> Encoding=UTF-8 
> Name=Security
> Icon=org.gnome.dspy
```

Comment: in security.menu after `<Include>`: `<Filename>appName.desktop</Filename>`

Comment: @stoney  Thank you!  But unfortunately that didnt' work.  

Are you sure I need to add a <Filename> tag for each app I wanted to add to this custom category?  I was hoping that for any app I wanted to put into the Security  category, I could just create .desktop files in ~/.local/usr/share/applications/ and edit the Category field to Security. The menu would automatically pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's, for posterity, and example that works:

Create a `.directory` file, careful, the naming of this file matters.

Save this file to: `$HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/work.directory`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Directory
Name=Work
Comment=Apps for Work
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/working-time-color.png
```

Create a `.menu` file -- of course the naming of the file matters, again.

Save this file to: `$HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/user-work.menu`:

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd">
<Menu>
  <Name>Applications</Name>
  <Menu>
    <Name>work</Name>
    <Directory>work.directory</Directory>
    <Include>
      <Filename>remote-viewer.desktop</Filename>
    </Include>
  </Menu>
</Menu>
```

Under the `<Include>` node you can include any of the user `.desktop` files (located under `~/.local/share/applications/`), or those available system-wide (located under `/usr/share/applications/`).

Reference: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/index.html